# Error MDAC higher than V2.6 required but V10.0 installed

Tags: database

We're trying to run a program that connects to SQL using ADO. It's been working fine for computers running Windows 7, but a new PC running Windows 10 is getting the below error

> *Application* cannot connect to a database via ADO wit ha version of
>   the Microsoft Data Access Components lower than version 2.6.
>
> MDAC v10.0 was detected on this machine, please contact your system
>   administrator.

I'm guessing the error is because alphabetically 10.0 comes before 2.6. Has anyone seen this error before? Any ideas on a work around?

Comment: This is a common programming mistake that developers have been making since version numbers were invented.

Answer (score 0):

I was just given more info after posting this question. The application is used for multiple legal entities. Some of those entities have been upgraded, some haven't.

The fix is to upgrade the application dll's to recognise v10.0 (will require vendor support) or run the application on a PC that doesn't have v10 installed (in our case, run Windows 7).